# Why does this unit test throw an "Element not found" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, uwp

I have created a very basic unit test for my C# project. The application is a thick client based on UWP so I am using Universal unit tests. I run the test and it fails with a `System.Exception: Element not found` message. It also says

> GetForCurrentView must be called on a thread that is associated with a CoreWindow

I've added the main project as a reference to the test project.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
namespace MyProjectTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ExampleObjectTest
    {
        private ExampleObject exampleObject;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            exampleObject = new ExampleObject();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void RequestParametersIsNotNullTest()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = exampleObject.MethodThatReturnsDictionary();
            Assert.IsNotNull(parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView()
ExampleObject.MethodThatReturnsDictionary()
ExampleObjectTest.RequestParametersIsNotNullTest()
```

This method does not return null but the test still fails. Is there further setup required in order to ensure this test passes?

Comment: Please post the full stack traces - that'll make it a lot clearer where the problem is.

Comment: @JonSkeet No problem. I've edited the question.

Comment: Right, well `MethodThatReturnsDictionary` is calling `DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView`, which is apparently somewhat UI-sensitive, in that it depends on the window the current thread is associated with... the method isn't "not returning null" - it's throwing an exception...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. Is there an appropriate way to ensure that the test runs on the correct thread? Or would it be more appropriate to mock this as technically I don't want to test something that also interacts with the view in this case?

Comment: I don't know enough about UWP to say, I'm afraid - but if this isn't really meant to be a UI-sensitive piece of code, then extracting the dependency makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @JonSkeet

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a static method inside a helper class to execute the given code on the UI thread.

**ThreadHelper.cs :**

```
    public static class ThreadHelper
    {

        public static IAsyncAction ExecuteOnUIThread(Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler action)
        {
            return Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        }
    }
```

and then inside your TestMethod:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task RequestParametersIsNotNullTest()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            await ThreadHelper.ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
            {
               exampleObject.MethodThatReturnsDictionary();
            });
            Assert.IsNotNull(parameters);
        }
```

Do not forget to replace void with **async Task**.